# how to back/forward user 's history by clicking the browser back/forward button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularjs page, it contains two part, the first part on the left is a navigation list with a list of news categories, the central content is the news list. so when people click one news category on the left, the central content will load the news list in ajax.

what I want to do now is,  when the user click the back or forward button on the browser, the browser could back / forward user to the last navigation link he clicked.

how can I  disable the browser back/ forward button 's default behavior and implement this in angular.js

Comment: Take a look at this guy's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/uDPHL/). I think it does what you want.

Comment: it is a good example, but I don't know how it works. my code is like app.controller('ListCtrl', function ($rootScope,$scope, $location) {  console.log( 'path' , $location.path()); } but the console's output is empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use $location
http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Manipulating-history-with-the-HTML5-History-API-and-AngularJS